# Where does iTunes keep information on played podcasts?

Tags: macos, itunes, podcasts

I wanted to check the name of a podcast I listened to four months ago and that got automatically deleted. I could not find that information on the iTunes tabs: "Unplayed", "Feed", "Saved". I restored the file from a backup, imported it again in iTunes, and now I see: `Played 27 May 2019` underneath it:

[image: iTunes showing a podcast as played after importing back a deleted podcast file]

So iTunes stores that information somewhere. I search for part of the title with `grep -r 'Stimulus' .` in the iTunes directory and only matched the binary file with the podcast episode.

Where does iTunes save information on played podcasts?